# How to capture " Android " phone screen as a video and store it in sd card. Don't want screenshot

Tags: android, video, screen, video-encoding

This is my first question in this site..! Quite a tough i guess..!

Actually i want to capture the phone screen (not emulator) for a time period say 15min and save it in sd card. I googled and learnt about Rooting.Rooting is not a constraint to me. I wanna capture the screen. I have no idea how to do this,

I just need your valuable suggesstion :

- How could i determine whether the phone has root access from my app..?
- How could i read each frame and record it..?

  ```
                   - Share your suggestions please..!
  ```

Thanks    - 
Mohan kumar

Comment: following links may be somewhat helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059309/java-applet-screen-capture-to-a-video and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504191/capture-live-video-from-webcam-using-java

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I went through the link you specified here.It was pretty helpful, I wanna capture the screen in android mobile. Does android supports swing,applet...? They were using those things. Lemme check(try) it out. I should show my gratitude for your response.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473) you will find sample code which reads directly from the framebuffer. Still you would need to convert the screenshots to video. 
You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk) for pointers how to do this.

Comment: Roger that sir, You bring me some confidence 2 complete this application. Thanks Renard.